# drag and drop doesnt work when redirected to a html with it

Tags: javascript, angularjs, drag-and-drop, draggable, drag

```js
var app = angular.module('main', ['ngRoute']);

app.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/', {
        templateUrl: './views/login.html',
        controller: 'loginController'
    }).when('/home', {
        resolve :{
            "check": function($location,$rootScope){
                if(!$rootScope.loggedIn){
                    $location.path('/');
                }
            }
        },
        templateUrl: './views/home.html',
        controller: 'homeController'
    })
    .otherwise({
        template: '404'
    })
});



app.controller('loginController', function($scope,$location,$rootScope) {
    $scope.login = function() {
        
        if($scope.username=="admin" && $scope.password=="admin"){
            $rootScope.loggedIn=true;
            $location.path('/home');
        }
        else $scope.error="Incorrect Username/Password!";
    }
});

app.controller('homeController', function($scope, user) {

});

const list_items = document.querySelectorAll('.list-item');
const lists = document.querySelectorAll('.list');

let draggedItem = null;

for (let i = 0; i < list_items.length; i++) {
    const item = list_items[i];

    item.addEventListener('dragstart', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        draggedItem = item;
        setTimeout(function () {
            item.style.display = 'none';
        }, 0)
    });

    item.addEventListener('dragend', function () {
        setTimeout(function () {
            draggedItem.style.display = 'block';
            draggedItem = null;
        }, 0);
    })

    for (let j = 0; j < lists.length; j ++) {
        const list = lists[j];

        list.addEventListener('dragover', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
        });
        
        list.addEventListener('dragenter', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            this.style.backgroundColor = 'rgba(224,245,179,0.5)';
        });

        list.addEventListener('dragleave', function (e) {
            this.style.backgroundColor = 'rgba(224,245,179,0.7)';
        });

        list.addEventListener('drop', function (e) {
            console.log('drop');
            this.append(draggedItem);
            this.style.backgroundColor = 'rgba(224,245,179,0.7)';
        });
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main">
        <div class="header">
            <h1 style="margin:0 auto">Kanban</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="lists">
            <div class="list">
                <h1> BACKLOG </h1>
                <div class="list-item" draggable="true">List item 1</div>
                <div class="list-item" draggable="true">List item 2</div>
                <div class="list-item" draggable="true">List item 3</div>
            </div>
            <div class="list">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I'm creating a simple app with login and a kanban board. When user logins site redirects him to kanban board. When I start html with kanban board (home.html) the drag and drop for list items works fine, but when I start try to first login and then access kanban board, kanban board is shown but drag and drop doesn't work.
I am trying to drag and drop list-items from one list to another

when a user click login it redirects to /home which is kanban board. so far I've only written it for admin but it doesn't matter for now.

Comment: I don't see the list in your implementation, where you define items, they are all static. It's also not defined in what list should those be dropped. Maybe check out the srouce code for this one: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/angularjs/angularjs_drag_application.htm